# How to limit the zoom of a time scale in d3.js to the minute?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3v4 chart using time scale on the x axis. Everything is working fine, but when I zoom in, it never stops. Is there a way to make it stop zooming when the minute scale is reached?

```
d3.scaleTime().range([0, width])
...
var zoom = d3.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
      .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
      .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
      .on("zoom", zoomed);
```

I am able to stop it from zooming if I change `Infinity` to some number, but the problem is that the size of the scale is different every time so the scale extent needed to reach the minute scale varies.

Comment: why not replace `Infinity` with a variable you calculate to help determine that?

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I was hoping there was something like `.scaleExtent(['month','minute'])`. That was be helpful.

Comment: @Matt did you find a work around?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set your `scaleExtent` to the proper values. If "the size of the scale is different every time", just set `scaleExtent` using the initial domain values:

```
var domainStart = new Date('1/1/2017'),
    domainEnd = new Date('2/1/2017');

var scale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([domainStart, domainEnd])
  .range([0, width])

...

// max zoom is the ratio of the initial domain extent to the minimum
// unit that you want to zoom to (1 minute == 1000*60 milliseconds)
var zoomMax = (domainEnd.getTime() - domainStart.getTime()) / (1000*60),
    zoomMin = 1;  

var zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([zoomMin, zoomMax])
  .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
  .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);
```

Comment: This is close. I probably described the problem wrong. This does zoom to the minute scale, as one full minute is stretched across the x-axis. What I am looking for is as you zoom in, I want the zoom to stop where every tick is one minute. Do not go further into seconds. So this would have to be a function of the graph width.